# Google Dev Tools is stopping execution when/where no breakpoints are set

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My Google Dev Tools has recently (after an apparent upgrade to v.32.0.1700.76) started [annoyingly] stopping script execution as if a breakpoint is set (see screenshot below).  Furthermore it is ignoring the “Deactivate Breakpoints” since with this option enabled script execution still stops at these phantom breakpoints.  I have no breakpoints set in any of the Dev Tools options – i.e., DOM breakpoints, XHR breakpoings, Event Listener breakpoints.  If I close the Dev Tools everything functions as normal.  Is anyone else experiencing this behaviour, and more importantly, know how to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: probably you clicked on the _pause_  symbol which would make the dev tools to break at exceptions.

Comment: Yup, that was it...!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chrome Dev Tools have not only the possibility to set break points in the code, or by certain events, but also for exception.

The *pause* symbol indicates if the dev tools breaks on all exceptions, only on uncaught or does not break at exceptions.
jQuery normally catches most of the exceptions, either to do feature detects, or just to detect another failure. So if the *pause* symbol is activated then the dev tool will stop there.

For development I would recommend to either place the source-map file and original source with the minified version or to use the not minified version, so that you will see where exactly the dev tool stop. Most of the time this will make it way easier to detect the problem yourself, and saves you time.