# Import/export Chrome devtools breakpoints & settings between computers

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Quoting [the original idea](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/YsphE1TzvbU/3Gtq_87PBwAJ):

> I came across a problem where I need to share all my debugger breakpoints to my colleague to debug the issue at his end. So thought of implementing something like export the debugger points from one system and import at other system.

Since devtools doesn't provide a built-in import/export feature, is there another way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Use devtools-on-devtools:

1. open **devtools** and switch its `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

   [image]
2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window

**UI method:**

3. in this new window switch to `Application` tab, expand `Local Storage`, then `devtools://devtools` on the left
4. double-click `breakpoints` value on the right and copypaste it
5. Now do the same on the target computer and reopen the main devtools window afterwards.

[image]

**Console method** (especially useful if the value is too long):

3. run `copy(localStorage.breakpoints)` in devtools-on-devtools console on the source computer to copy the value to clipboard
4. run `localStorage.breakpoints=prompt()` on the target computer
   (the prompt will appear in the main devtools window).

**Console method to export everything:**

3. run `copy(JSON.stringify(localStorage))` in devtools-on-devtools console on the source computer to copy the value to clipboard
4. run `Object.assign(localStorage, JSON.parse(prompt()))` on the target computer
   (the prompt will appear in the main devtools window).

P.S. Next time you can quickly toggle the detached state of devtools by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: wow..thanks..this should be circulated in mainstream news..

Comment: Better yet, they should add export/import in devtools UI.

Comment: yeah.. exactly.. I suffer from adding a large no of breakpoints.. this'll help me a lot. I'm so glad to find it out in my early career(kind of :)).. thanks again mate..

Comment: `Cmd+Shift+i` doesn't do anything for me. Is there a different way to open devtools-on-devtools?

Comment: It's cmd-option-i.