# Is it possible to easily move breakpoints in devtools? How do you stop breakpoints from moving in devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I'm using devtools to debug my JavaScript code. Is there a way to keep the breakpoints from moving when I make changes to my code? When I make changes to the file, the breakpoint is firing on code where I don't want it to be on instead of the code I originally wanted it to fire on.

Or is there a way to do some sort of drag-and-dropping of breakpoints in devtools to at least easily move them back to where I want the breakpoint to fire? I keep having to delete the breakpoint and then add it back to the area I wanted. I tried clicking and dragging but it just deletes the breakpoint.

Comment: There's no way. You can suggest adding it in devtools e.g. a shift command in the right-click menu for a breakpoint. A clumsy workaround would be to edit the breakpoints manually as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58917682).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I'll suggest it. Also thanks for the alternative suggestion as well, didn't know we could do that.